# Take two rows of data at once and put the data into two columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

What SQL code will transform the input table to the output table in this example? (Assume some ordering, odd rows go to column2 and even rows go to column3 with consecutive odd-even pairs on the same output row.)

```
input table:
column1
  A
  B
  C
  D
  E
  F

output table:
column2    column3
  A          B
  C          D
  E          F
```

**Update:**
Assuming some ordering, odd rows go to column2 and even rows go to column3 with consecutive odd-even pairs on the same output row

Comment: It's more than completely unclear what are the conditions to split data among these tables. Please elaborate.

Comment: Assuming some ordering, odd rows go to column2 and even rows go to column3 with consecutive odd-even pairs on the same output row.

Comment: @user1744318 I think you should place this comment inside the question.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
;WITH CTE AS (
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY column1) AS rn, column1
  FROM #mytable
), CTE2 AS (
   SELECT *
   FROM CTE 
   WHERE rn % 2 <> 0
), CTE3 AS (
   SELECT *
   FROM CTE 
   WHERE rn % 2 = 0
)
SELECT c2.column1 AS column2, c3.column1 AS column3
FROM CTE2 AS c2
LEFT JOIN CTE3 AS c3 ON c2.rn = c3.rn - 1
```

`CTE2` contains all odd rows, whereas `CTE3` contains all even rows. We join consecutive odd - even pairs together by `c2.rn = c3.rn - 1` to get the desired result set.

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/bec9d/1)

Comment: Thats the idea which I tried to use but resulted in downvotes :(

Comment: Isn't using a join overkill here?

Answer (score 1):

This method accommodates easily changing the number of output columns

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT
    column1
   ,output_row = (ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY column1)-1) / 2 
   ,output_col = (ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY column1)-1) % 2
  FROM input_table
)
SELECT
  column2 = [0]
 ,column3 = [1]
FROM cte
PIVOT(MAX(column1) FOR output_col IN ([0],[1])) p
```

Comment: Change `(ORDER BY column1)` to whatever you want.